# My C Programmingworking

Tags: c, xcode

And the two functions are:

```
void readFromFile(char file[], int antal_varor, struct storagemanipulation 
*inventory)
{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fp==fopen("minFil.txt","r")
```

This is the bug.

```
fp=fopen("minFil.txt","r")
```

will be the correct way.

You can do it simply like this

```
fp=fopen("minFil.txt","r");
if( fp == NULL ){
// error
}
else{
// do cool stuff
}
```

This is much more readable. Less error prone.

Also op is writing to the same file from which content was read. maybe the file where it is to be written is different.

Comment: @AbdirahmanMohamed no compiler warning like *'==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='?*

Comment: @WeatherVane.: I guess OP didn't notice it.

Comment: oops changed to a different warning - but still a warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane.: I meant in general..for this compiler throws an warning AFAIR.

Comment: @coderredoc Thanks for your response. I did the changes that you mentioned in your answer but the program is still not saving the inputs

Comment: @AbdirahmanMohamed.: By the way you are writing to the same file from which you read. That is what you want?

Comment: @coderredoc yes i want the program to read from the same file.

Comment: @coderredoc precisely. is that wrong? or is there a better way that i can save my input and read them when i run the program again?

Comment: @AbdirahmanMohamed.: Bigger question is how do you check the file is not saved? I mean it's the same file as before. And you put it in the file the same way. So how you say that it failed?

Comment: @coderredoc what i am trying to say is that when i reboot my program all the input are no longer there. so there must be something wrong with file functions. right?

Comment: @AbdirahmanMohamed.: Well check one thing, write to a different file first and check how it works. You will get a better idea.

Comment: @coderredoc did u find any other mistake that would make the file i/o not work properly?